# Insert Row Into 2 Tables Linked w/Foregin Key Only If The Dependable Table's Insert Succeeds (Without Transaction)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert, multiple-insert

I have two MySQL tables and I need to insert a record in each of them. Caveat: The insert into dependable table may fail due to duplicate key conflict. In that case none of the rows should be inserted.

```
CREATE TABLE `meanings` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `aliases` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `meaningId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `phrase` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `phrase_UNIQUE` (`phrase`),
  KEY `meaning_IDX` (`meaningId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Synonyms_1` FOREIGN KEY (`meaningId`) REFERENCES `meanings` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

In a nutshell I need to do following but faster:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO aliases (phrase, meaningId) VALUES ('word1', NULL);
SELECT IF(row_count() > 0, last_insert_id(), 0) INTO @aliasId;
INSERT INTO meanings (id) SELECT null FROM aliases WHERE id=@aliasId;
SELECT IFNULL(last_insert_id(), 0) INTO @meaningId;
UPDATE aliases SET meaningId=@meaningId WHERE id=@aliasId;
```

My constraints/conditions/wishes:

1. The SQL table scheme is given as above (although new cols can be added)
2. Avoid using transactions
3. Avoid using `DELETE FROM meanings`
4. Account for many processes doing the same thing simultaneously
5. Optimize for mass insert of average of ~40 aliases at the time
6. Minimize locks
7. Records are permanent and will never be removed

My thoughts:

- Comfortable way would be `trigger after insert` on `aliases` that inserts a row into `meanings` and updates back inserted row's `aliases.meaningId` but I am worried about performance
- In worst case I can do transactions if they are performant enough when compared to other solutions. This is a routine that may be called inside other transactions so avoiding transactions would be preferable.
- Performance on dozens of inserts at the time is the key factor (using PHP).

**QUESTION**: What is the fastest solution to insert ~40 (possibly conflicting) records into `aliases` at the time with corresponding records in `meaning` table?

It seems that this use case scenario is so common that something back in my head keeps saying that I might lack some knowledge of existing trivial solutions/inbuilt support for this particular case that is both more elegant and more efficient (then the solution I came up with bellow).

Note: The table is really 1:n even though in this example it behaves strictly 1:1. In my use case the data start their life cycle as 1:1 but later on their `meaning` can change...

---

*The example of desired result*

Before insert:

```
SELECT * FROM meanings;

# id
  1 
  2 
  3 

SELECT meaningId, phrase FROM aliases;

# meaningId       phrase
  1               word1
  2               word2
  3               word3
```

Now I need to insert in highly optimized way values `word3` (note this one already exists), `word4`, `word5` so the result is this:

```
SELECT * FROM meanings;

# id
  1 
  2 
  3 
  4
  5

SELECT meaningId, phrase FROM aliases;

# meaningId       phrase
  1               word1
  2               word2
  3               word3
  4               word4
  5               word5
```

Comment: Please give an example of, say, 3 rows already in the table.  Then show, say, 3 rows to add and the resulting contents of the tables.

Comment: It sounds like the tables supposed to be 1:1.  If so, why have two separate tables?

Comment: Nope. One `meaning` can have multiple `aliases` (1:n). But the data cycle starts with `alias` having its own `meaning` (thus initially 1:1). Later on another process identifies that "aliases" may mean the same thing. E.g. "red", "rot", "červený" represent the same word/meaning... Hm. I guess that I could have, for the sake of the argument, have it 1:1 for this question. You are right. But people would rightly ask then why to have two tables. :-)

Comment: I added examples of what is in the table and what should be in it after the operation.

Comment: I suspect that your example was not updated adequately.  `SELECT id FROM meanings` gives the same resultset as `SELECT meaningId FROM aliases`, so I don't see the point.

Comment: If you would care to try and copy & paste examples you would get the very same results. What point are you looking for?

Comment: `word1` as a "phrase" does not talk to me.  Switch to red, rot, green, verdant and show how you want the aliases to be.

Comment: Ah. I see. This is an example of 5 distinct words that are not aliases. Aliasing is the next step in my program that I don't need any help with. All words are initially not-aliased. So think of it as "word1"="red", 'word2'='blue', 'word3'='green', 'word4'='orange', 'word5'='cyan'. No aliases. I need to insert 5 distinct words into DB fast (+5 records in each table). I need to insert 0 records next time if I try to do it with the very same words. It is really that simple. The explanation with red=rot=... was just to explain why it is 1:n. I think I found the fastest solution - see below.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could come up with given all the circumstances and constraints is this:

```
ALTER TABLE `meanings` 
ADD COLUMN `initialAliasId` INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `initialAliasId_UNIQUE` (`initialAliasId` ASC);

INSERT IGNORE INTO aliases (phrase) VALUES ('word1'), ('word2'), ('word3');

INSERT IGNORE INTO meanings (initialAliasId) SELECT id FROM aliases WHERE meaningId IS NULL;

UPDATE aliases as a LEFT JOIN meanings as m ON (m.initialAliasId = a.id) 
SET a.meaningId = m.id WHERE a.meaningId IS NULL;
```

- Supports multiple inserts at the time
- Minimizes both locks and overhead that comes with separate requests
- No tansactions/rollbacks